# Can Liquibase compare data of two of two databases with diff command using difftypes=data?

Tags: liquibase

I'm a new to `Liquibase`. I have used the following command
but is not giving expected result. Can `Liquibase` compare data of two of two databases?

```
c:\LiquiBase>liquibase --username=root --url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema3 --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --referenceUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/solution --referenceUsername=root --diffTypes=data diff diffChangeLog > change.xml
```

Comment: When reporting something unexpected, always include 3 things: 1. This is what I did (you almost have this - you are missing enough information about the database setup). 2. This is what I expected to happen (you are missing this). 3. This is what actually happened (you are missing this as well).

Comment: I have created two databases in mysql, out of two one contains tables with data and another contains only empty tables. I expect from above command it should given the difference  of data  and generate the changelog.But it is not giving data diff it is just giving the structure difference..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you are actually giving liquibase TWO commands (both diff and diffChangelog) and the code is using the second.

Answer (score 1):

Liquibase can't create a data changeset with the `diff` or `diffChangeLog` command. `--diffTypes=data` is only available for the `generateChangeLog` command.

Find more information [here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html).

So, you could get data as a Liquibase changeset only with full schema generation.

Answer (score -2):

$ liquibase --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver         --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl      --username=user         --password=password     diffChangeLog    --referenceDriver=org.sqlite.JDBC  --referenceUrl=jdbc:sqlite:/sqlite/temp.db         --referenceUsername=user         --referencePassword=password > diff.SQL